# String that will automatically split into 2 columns

Tags: excel, character-encoding

Is it possible to paste a string into excel such that it automatically parses into 2 columns?

I have to assume a fresh unopened version of excel so I can't do things like setting the text-to-columns wizard or using macros.

I'm basically looking for a string character that will be interpreted as a tab no matter what similar to how cl_abap_char_utilities=>horizontal_tab works in SAP/OLE2.

I've tried

```
="String1" & CHAR(09) & "String2"
```

and

```
"String1     String2" (Using TAB on keyboard)
```

and

```
=SUBSTITUTE("String 1 # String2", "#", CHAR(9))
```

and none work

Answer (score 0):

If your string is delimited with tabs (ASCII code 9), it will automatically split into columns upon paste.

Comment: Edited the question. How would I use this?

Comment: You can insert a tab character into cell with `CHAR(9)` but it won't display. However, you can copy the values, paste them to Notepad, copy the resulting text and paste it back to your workbook to parse the text into columns.

Comment: Like how I tried in the question? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "...and none work". Is the tab character visible? No. Is the tab character *actually there?* Yes. Can you split the text by copying it to Notepad and back? Yes.

Comment: I mean if I paste the string I've got in my question it doesn't split across columns.

Comment: Are you pasting values or formulas?

Comment: Values - just text strings